# htaccess redirect a plus sign

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I try to make a redirect of a URL from my old site to my new site, but it does not work.
I think that the plus symbol is giving me problems.

```
  RewriteRule ^nl/pageid/junair+compressor+onderhoud(|/)$     /nl/persluchttechniek/page/nieuwsberichten/compressor-onderhoud-junair  [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this redirect rule in your root .htaccess of old site:

```
RewriteRule ^nl/pageid/junair[\s+]compressor[\s+]onderhoud/?$ /nl/persluchttechniek/page/nieuwsberichten/compressor-onderhoud-junair [NC,B<R=301,L]
```

Make sure this is your very first rule below `RewriteEngine` line. Also check there is no other .htaccess in your system.

Answer (score 0):

The + is presumably a URL encoded space, try replacing it in the pattern with a \s.

```
RewriteRule ^nl/pageid/junair\scompressor\sonderhoud(|/)$     /nl/persluchttechniek/page/nieuwsberichten/compressor-onderhoud-junair  [R=301,L]
```