# htaccess redirect url with special characters (+)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like this.

http://olddomain.com/product-category/x-tended+bottoms/

and I wanted to apply a 301 redirect via htaccess to http://newdomain.com/shop/extended-bottoms

However, when i'm trying to apply a rule that goes like this, it doesn't take effect and instead lands me to page not found.

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/product-category/x-tended+bottoms/(.*)$ https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/shop/all-bottoms?`

What regex can I use to change the plus sign (+) on the url?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to find a reference answer to my question by adding the highlighted rule to check the plus sign (+) on URLs:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/product-category/x-tended**[\s+]**bottoms/$ https://newdomain.com/?$
```

[htaccess redirect a plus sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016789/htaccess-redirect-a-plus-sign/27018567#27018567)