# htaccess redirect all urls ending with a text to another text with a + in the url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

The CMS I use creates duplicate product urls with a `+` sign in the url and this cannot be change.

Now I want to redirect directly all urls their end part to the same url with a different end part

example
`test/test2/articles/g+c+ch+a+nr+view`
to
`test/test2/groups/g+c+ch+a+nr+view`

the only difference is the articles and groups but the last piece (g+c+ch+a+nr+view) has to go with it because that makes sure it only happens to the products and not in other places

I have tried different things but I have not succeeded

the following things I tried:

```bash
#RewriteRule ^(.*)articles/g\+c\+ch\+a\+nr\+view$ $1groups/g+c+ch+a+nr+view [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)articles/g.c.ch.a.nr.view[^&]+
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}groups/g+c+ch+a+nr+view [QSA,R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^articles/g.c.ch.a.nr.view$

RewriteRule (.*) /$1?groups/g+c+ch+a+nr+view [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)articles/g.c.ch.a.nr.view$ groups/g+c+ch+a+nr+view [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)articles/g.c.ch.a.nr.view$ /$1/groups/g+c+ch+a+nr+view [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)articles/g+c+ch+a+nr+view$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Remember how _you_ asked about problems with matching plus signs, back in 2014 ...? https://stackoverflow.com/q/27016789/1427878 (so at least the matching part you should be able to get done now, _without_ much guesswork or trial-and-error.)

Comment: that question has the relationship on another problem

Comment: `example test/test2/articles/` - is `test` supposed to be the host name here now, or is it a folder below the domain root? On which level is your .htaccess file placed?

Comment: test is a folder below the domain root yes

Answer (score 0):

I have already found the solution

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)articles/g\+c\+ch\+a\+nr\+view$
RewriteRule ^ %1groups/g+c+ch+a+nr+view [R=301,L]
```

the following also works

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)articles/g.c.ch.a.nr.view$
RewriteRule ^ %1groups/g+c+ch+a+nr+view [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Bit superfluous to use a RewriteCond to perform a check the RewriteRule could have already done on its own.

Comment: maybe I am not explaining properly then.
but I am trying to use 1 line to redirect all urls ending with this to the same url with a different ending.
I couldn't get this done with just a RewriteRule
You should think of the plus part as a parameter

Comment: All I am saying is, that what RewriteRule matches against, is the URL path. So there is no need to use a RewriteCond to check on the contents of the URL path, the RewriteRule can already do that on its own. Just `RewriteRule ^(.*)articles/g.c.ch.a.nr.view$ $1groups/g+c+ch+a+nr+view [R=301,L]` should work pretty much the same way here.

Comment: I tried that one too but then it sends me all the way back to the base url: example.com/
but I think this is due to something specific in the CMS we use that redirects all kinds of things automatically